# How to get the hashed password to pass into my database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am able to run a test in Postman, but for some reason I am not passing my hashed password into the DB correctly.

```
const express = require("express");
// const helmet = require("helmet");
const { User } = require("./db/models");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
var salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
var hash = bcrypt.hashSync('bacon', 8);

const port = 4000;

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: "50mb" }));

// app.use(helmet());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello World!");
});
```

Here is where i suspect the issue is. I am passing the name, email, and password in. I am trying to figure out how to get the hash to pass into the DB as the password.

```
app.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.create({name:req.body.name, email:req.body.email, password:req.body.password});

  bcrypt.genSalt().then(salt => {
    bcrypt.hash("password", salt).then(hash =>{
      console.log(hash);
    });
  })

  console.log(req.body.name)
  res.json(user);
 
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are in an async function you can use await to get the values before creating the User object

```
app.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
  const hashed_password = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password,salt);
  const user = await User.create({name:req.body.name, email:req.body.email, password:hased_password});
  console.log(req.body.name)
  res.json(user);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const hashedPwd = await bcrypt.genSalt().then(salt => {
  return bcrypt.hash("password", salt);
})
```

is that you want?

Comment: Where would I pass in hashedPwd?

Comment: same as Girish Srivatsa post, you got user input from `req.body.password` and hash it, then store it in user.

Answer (score -1):

You have to save the user collection. That is, after hashing the password, the user's password must be changed.

user.password = hash;
user.save()

Comment: `.create()` creates and saves the object, no need to call `.save()`.